# How to get the counts of rows in each fifth of data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table with a single integer column.

```
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 score  | integer |
```

Assuming this could have a large number of rows over an arbitrary range of values, how would I:

1. Split into 5 parts (by value, not by count).  So `(max - min) / 5` would be the range size for each section.
2. Get the count inside of each of those sections

So for example, if the values of `score` were `(100, 101, 145, 170, 171, 172, 200)` I'd like to get a result like so:

```
 range   |  count
---------+-------
 100-120 |   2
 121-140 |   0
 141-160 |   1
 161-180 |   3
 181-200 |   1
```

I can get it to work with `group by` if i know the ranges, but they will vary depending on the data.

Comment: In 2 queries, you could calculate max and min, and then group by score/((max-min)/5). Integer division will do the magic.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to work, except when the count(*) is zero, the range doesn't get displayed.  How would I make it show the zero count?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
WITH stats AS (
  SELECT generate_series(0,4) block, min(score), max(score), 
         ceil(max(val)-min(val))/5.0)::int4 size
  FROM the_table
)
SELECT block, block * size + min || '-' || (block + 1) * size + min - 1 AS range, count(score)
FROM stats
LEFT JOIN the_table ON(block = (score - min) / size)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1
```

Note the `ceil()::int4`, with just integer division you'll miss the largest values unless your range happens to divide evenly into the number of parts you want.